# Why can't I change a composer package namepace?

Tags: namespaces, composer-php, vendor

I'm confused as to why I can't change a namespace for a composer package. I'm running a laravel application with a package in my vendor directory.

So, my `composer.json` for this package includes:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Spatie\\Backup\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to alter the namespace, for example:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Spatie\\Backupdatabase\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the autoloader the file `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`  still contains the original namespace and not the updated one. I've tried running

```json
$ composer clear cache
```

but that doesn't make a difference.

I thought that composer autoloaded by running through the packages in the vendor directory looking for `composer.json` files and autoloading from the 'autoload' section within, but I am now wondering if that is the case.

What am I missing? Why will it not autoload with a new namespace?

Update

I think the reason an edit to a namespacing in a package composer.json doesn't update the psr4 file is due to the installed.json file. This file contains what has actually been installed and the designated namespace. If I change the namespace for the package in this file and run the autoloader then the updated namespace will take effect.  can't find much information on this file through the composer docs - I'm not sure when it gets over written?

Comment: Note that the `Spatie` namespace is already in use and registered, see https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/. You might run into issues if you depend on any of these packages, or intend to publish yours.

Comment: Hi @localheinz, I'm just using a Spatie package to track the issue down. I have run the autoloader and it doesn't make a difference. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *running the autoloader*?

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting the autoloading configuration in `composer.json`, you need to run

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Comment: Have you even tried what I suggested here? This should be the accepted solution as it is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: I have run composer dump-autoload but this does not work by itself. The changes only take place If I remove installed.json in the composer folder first.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a namespace is not advisable, even if you have forked the package.  Instead, please consider something like this...

1. fork the package
2. make only the changes you absolutely need
3. add the location of your fork to the repositories section of composer.json in your target project (not the forked package's composer file).
4. Composer should now fetch the altered version of the package into your project's vendor dir.
5. consider making a pull request